# Trying out the h2o autoML option preprocessing = ["target_encoding"]. How to handle and check performance in the unseen data?

Tags: python, target, h2o, automl, data-preprocessing

Trying out the h2o autoML option preprocessing = ["target_encoding"].The test performance did improve. How do I apply similar transformation on the unseen/ out of time data to check performance?